# How to pass this type of data in Post Api Call inFlutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass the body to post api which is like below:

```
    {
      "firstname": "Demo",
      "lastname": "User",
      "email": "nash11@vipmail.hu",
      "password": "password",
      "confirm": "password",
      "telephone": "1-541-754-3010",
      "customer_group_id": 1,
      "agree": 1,
      "custom_field": {
        "account": {
          "1": "+364545454"
        }
      }
    }
```

and my problem is how to pass this section.

```
    "custom_field": {
        "account": {
          "1": "+364545454"
        }
      }
```

if am trying to pass in

```
Map<Strng,dynamic>` data = 

    {
      "firstname": "Demo",
      "lastname": "User",
      "email": "nash11@vipmail.hu",
      "password": "password",
      "confirm": "password",
      "telephone": "1-541-754-3010",
      "customer_group_id": 1,
      "agree": 1,
      "custom_field": {
        "account": {
          "1": "+364545454"
        }
      }
    }
```

it showing error

```
    type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

this may help you:

```
"https://opencart3-simple.api.opencart-api.com/api/rest/register" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "X-Oc-Session: 8d63ab88c43d2ebdda1b219a98" -H  "X-Oc-Merchant-Id: 123" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{  \"firstname\": \"Demo\",  \"lastname\": \"User\",  \"email\": \"nash111@vipmail.hu\",  \"password\": \"password\",  \"confirm\": \"password\",  \"telephone\": \"1-541-754-3010\",  \"customer_group_id\": 1,  \"agree\": 1,  \"custom_field\": {    \"account\": {      \"1\": \"+364545454\"    }  }}"
```

Comment: Please add a code that is responsible for calling the API endpoint.

Comment: I have edit the question. Please go through it @AndreyGordeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your data and follow the convention

```
var response = await _dio.post("$url",
          options: header, data: jsonEncode(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Map<Strng,dynamic>` data = 

    {
      "firstname": "Demo",
      "lastname": "User",
      "email": "nash11@vipmail.hu",
      "password": "password",
      "confirm": "password",
      "telephone": "1-541-754-3010",
      "customer_group_id": 1,
      "agree": 1,
      "custom_field": jsonEncode({
        "account": {
          "1": "+364545454"
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like that :

```
  var data = {}; 

  data["firstname"] = "Demo";
  data["lastname"] = "User";
  data["email"] = "nash11@vipmail.hu";
  data["password"] ="password";
```

and pass like this

```
 var response = await _dio.post($url,
           data: jsonEncode(data));
```